# How to implement a Linked List with const data in C?

Tags: c

Note: This question was closed before saying that it is associated with another question asked previously. However, it DOES NOT answer this question as it recommended to not just use const in that answer. I will have to use const as this is a required part of the project.

I am trying to make a program that implements a doubly linked list with a const data field. I can implement a conventional linked list without a problem, but I can't come up to a solution where the data field for the list is constant. The list will be read from a text file using `program.c < textfile.txt`.

This is my C struct for the initialization:

```
struct node {
    int const data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
```

Can anyone please help me with how to proceed with this? I will eventually need to have a sorting algorithm which will sort the list. I already have the code to sort the list working, but that is without the const declaration.

I get the following error with const:

```
error: assignment of read-only member ‘data’
```

After lots of looking up online, the only thing that seems to be recommended is doing some pointer trickery to achieve this. But that is not working as well.
I would really appreciate your help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can this entire question be narrowed to “assign const struct member”? Being a linked list seems _entirely irrelevant_.

Comment: you aren't giving enough code, why are you assigning to a const? I'm guessing because you've malloced the node?